# ¿Por que mi cookie no es guardada por el navegador?

Tags: cors, cookies, fastapi

He estado complicado con una cuestion sobre cookies. Estoy trabajando con fastapi y next.js donde mi objetivo es cuando se llama al endpoint se haga un set_cookie en la respuesta.

Unicamente en Chrome (pero no en firefox) me guarda la cookie con lo siguiente:

```
response.set_cookie(key="sessionID", value=str(id), expires=3600*2, samesite='None', secure=True, httponly=True)
```

En mi enviroment local estoy corriendo en https tanto el back como el front pero me parece raro que en firefox no se guarde. Ademas cuando quiero hacer get de la cookie del header en el back tampoco lo recibe por mas que esta exista del lado del cliente.

El CORS ya tiene permitido el dominio 'https://localhost:3000'. en la peticion el credentials tambien esta

```
        const backurl = `https://127.0.0.1:8000/authcookie?ip=${ip}`;
        const settings = {
          method: 'GET',
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            
          },
          credentials: 'include'
        };
        const response = await fetch(backurl,settings)
```